# Inserir na Query String somente os valores das checkboxes selecionadas com suas respectivas quantidades

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tendo um pequeno problema em montar uma Query String com as variáveis que necessito.
Bom, tenho a seguinte parte de código:

```
echo "<form class='acrescimos'>";               
foreach($conexao->query($sql2) as $acrescimo)
{
    $preco_acrescimo_reajustado = number_format($acrescimo['preco_acrescimo'], 2, ",", ".");
    echo "
    <input class='caixa-acrescimo' type='checkbox' name='id_acrescimo' value='{$acrescimo['id_acrescimo']}'/>{$acrescimo['nome_acrescimo']} - R&#36;{$preco_acrescimo_reajustado} <input type='number' name='quantidade_acrescimo' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
    ";
}
echo "</form>";
```

Nesse trecho de código eu obtenho os valores do DB e insiro cada um deles em uma checkbox.
Agora, para pegar os valores das checkboxes selecionadas eu uso jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.adicionar').on('submit', function()
    {
        var id_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id-produto').text();
        var nome_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.nome-produto').text();
        var quantidade = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input.caixa-acrescimo').is(':checked'))
        {
            var acrescimos = $(this).closest('tr').find( '.acrescimos' ).serialize();
            window.location.href = "adicionar.php?id_produto=" + id_produto + "&nome_produto=" + nome_produto + "&quantidade=" + quantidade + "&acrescimos=" + acrescimos;
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href = "adicionar.php?id_produto=" + id_produto + "&nome_produto=" + nome_produto + "&quantidade=" + quantidade;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Vamos supor que apenas a checkbox de valor `1` está selecionada e no input em frente referente à sua quantidade o valor é `3`. Meu *output* deverá ser algo como:
`adicionar.php?id_produto=4&nome_produto=Pizza de Bacon&quantidade=1&acrescimos=id_acrescimo=1&quantidade_acrescimo=3`
É aí que se encontra o meu pequeno problema. Eu até tenho parte do *output* como eu quero, mas os valores dos outros inputs de quantidade também são inseridos ao serializar, ficando assim:
`adicionar.php?id_produto=4&nome_produto=Pizza de Bacon&quantidade=1&acrescimos=id_acrescimo=1&quantidade_acrescimo=3&quantidade_acrescimo=1&quantidade_acrescimo=1`
Como fazer com que apenas os inputs de quantidade referentes às checkboxes selecionadas constem na Query String? Obrigado!

Comment: Eu acredito que quando você está executando a função .serialize(), está retornando vários elementos '.acrescimos'. Acho que um .filter() resolve o seu problema.
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.acrescimos').filter(function(indice, elemento){
        /* Coloque uma lógica aqui. */
        return true;
    }).serialize();

Comment: @WédneyYuri Este parece ser o caminho, mas não sei como relacionar o input da checkbox com o input de quantidade para então poder usar esta função para obter as quantidades somente dos acréscimos que estão selecionados.